# xlsxwrter: rich text format in chart title

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

is it possible to use rich text format and special characters in chart titles and labels with `xlsxwriter`, or with any other python-excel module (e.g. `openpyxl`)?

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('rich_text_in_chart_title.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

subscript = workbook.add_format({'font_script': 2})

worksheet.write_rich_string('A1',
                            'H',
                            subscript, '2',
                            'O'
                            )

# Add the worksheet data to be plotted
data = [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50]
worksheet.write_column('A3', data)

# Create a new chart object
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Add a series to the chart
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$3:$A$8'})

chart.set_title({'name': 'alpha: H2O'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('C1', chart)

workbook.close()
```

I want to replace the `alpha` in the chart title with a greek letter and the `H20` with a subscripted 2 as it is in cell A1.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to use rich text format and special characters in chart titles and labels with xlsxwriter

No. That isn't supported.

However you could create the caption you need using UTF-8 Unicode, like this Python3 example:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart_column.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

worksheet.write_column('A2', [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],)

chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6'})

chart.set_title ({'name': 'α: H₂O'})

worksheet.insert_chart('C2', chart)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How can I create these UTF-8 Unicode strings?