# Subscript letters in Excel chart

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66601757/xlsxwrter-rich-text-format-in-chart-title), I need subscript capital letters in an Excel chart, generated by a python script with xlsxwriter.

[jmcnamara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10238/jmcnamara) suggested to use UTF-8 Unicode. I need the letters 'IT' as subscript, as far as I now Unicode doesn't support those letters.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Unicode workaround in the other post there isn't any way to do this in XlsxWriter. It is also unlikely to be supported in the future due to the API and internal complexity.

When answering the other question I thought that it might be possible to format the string in a cell and then link to it for the title. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in Excel and instead it shows the unformatted string.

So I don't know any other option unless openpyxl supports it, or xlwings.

Comment: I see. If it was possible to use different font sizes, I could use a small capital instead ob subscripting. 2017 this was not possible: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/410 What about today?

Comment: Supporting different fonts is the same more or less the same issue as supporting subscripts. That is unlikely to be supported either.